# How to disable power on/off beep on UPS (CyberPower CP1350PFC)

Tags: ups

I've had a couple UPS in the past, but the beep on this UPS (CyberPower CP1350PFCLCD) is a little obnoxious and loud.

The "mute notifications" button only stops it from beeping during a power outage, and their included software doesn't have anything to stop it from beeping when I turn it on / off.

I'm fine with a beep to let be know it is on / off, but I don't want it to beep for the solid 2 seconds when holding the button to toggle it on / off.

Is there anyway to disable (or at least reduce the volume) the beep without messing with the speaker itself?

Comment: If there isn't an option in the software, that would typically indicate, there isn't a way to disable this particular beep notification.  Have you contacted CyberPower with regards to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just opened it and covered hole in the beeper with thick tape. That reduced the sound for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what the situation was five years ago, but CyberPower's PowerPanel Personal software on Windows does have an option under the Advanced section to disable the alarm, at least for my older CyberPower CP600LCD. That said, it seems that I have to re-set that option in the software every time the unit has been powered down.